# Decoding oneof proto fields with tf.io.decode_proto

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm using tf.io.decode_proto to parse some custom protobufs in a way that can be used inside @tf.functions. This seems to work fine when accessing message fields, but it raises an unknown field error when trying to access something declared as a oneof (not the fields inside it).

Is there any way to get something similar to proto.WhichOneof(oneof_field) using tf.io.decode_proto? If possible I'd rather avoid getting all possible fields inside the oneof and iterating them to see which one (if any) has non-empty data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any workarounds, but a good way to resolve this is to fix the op itself; the error probably comes from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_proto_op.cc#L663). It's worth filing an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new/choose) to see if anyone might be able to help.